# No horizontal scroll in Safari. Bug, or pref?

Tags: safari, macos

Mac Pro 5,1 Mojave, Safari [latest] 14.1

Since the last Safari update in the last week, I've lost the ability to shift/scroll to move horizontally.
Fine in Chrome, Finder etc, this seems to just be Safari.
Did a pref slip somewhere? I've never really tried to find if this is a pref, I thought it 'just happened'.

If it's a bug I'll report it, but I'd like to know if I missed a pref.

Screenshot hopefully wide enough to display this. Click the image, then if you see a magnifying glass with a + in it when you hover your cursor over the letters, click again so it goes beyond your window size [or repeatedly tap  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>+</kbd>  until it no longer fits the window].
Hold Shift & scroll mouse wheel.

[image]

It would be interesting to know if this affects trackpads too, but I don't have one to test.

Comment: macOS 11.3.1, Safari 14.1, iMac mid-2015: Safari's horizontal scrolling displays and works as expected. I also have no trackpad to test with.

Comment: macOS 11.4 beta 2 (sorry only Mac available), Safari 14.1.1, works fine for me with shift-scroll on normal mouse (and also Magic mouse and trackpad). Have you tried a new user account, should rule out preferences?

Comment: I'm also unable to reproduce this with Safari 14.1.1

Comment: Meh, another account is clean. I'll have to do some more fiddling...

Comment: Current suspect is AdGuard. Switching it off & refreshing returns functionality. Switching it back on… retains functionality, but only for 'some time'. Return later & it once again fails. I have yet to work out what triggers the fail. I posted a bug report at AdGuard, but my input info is vague. I may need them to check back with me for more specific tests..

Comment: Working with the developer on this, does seem to be one component of AdGuard, Web Annoyances Ultralist. Looks like a resolution will not be far away.

Comment: bug report link - https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardFilters/issues/82833

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update*
Now seems to be fixed in latest release of AdGuard.

---

It's an issue with AdGuard, specifically the *Web Annoyances Ultralist*.

Reported to the developers in https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardFilters/issues/82833

with a dev response

> Ok, better disable this filter. It can break something in Safari, also our filters compiler has one issue [AdguardTeam/SafariConverterLib#21](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/SafariConverterLib/issues/21)
> After release which will contain the fix for problem above, you can try that filter again.

I have that filter disabled for now & will test again after the next release.